# python not properly reading in text file

Tags: python, text-files

I'm trying to read in a text file that looks something like this:

```
Date, StartTime, EndTime 
6/8/14, 1832, 1903
6/8/14, 1912, 1918
6/9/14, 1703, 1708
6/9/14, 1713, 1750
```

and this is what I have:

```
g = open('Observed_closure_info.txt', 'r')
closure_date=[]
closure_starttime=[]
closure_endtime=[]
file_data1 = g.readlines()
for line in file_data1[1:]:
    data1=line.split(', ')
    closure_date.append(str(data1[0]))
    closure_starttime.append(str(data1[1]))
    closure_endtime.append(str(data1[2]))
```

I did it this way for a previous file that was very similar to this one, and everything worked fine. However, this file isn't being read in properly. First it gives me an error "list index out of range" for `closure_starttime.append(str(data1[1]))` and when I ask for it to print what it has for data1 or closure_date, it gives me something like

```
['\x006\x00/\x008\x00/\x001\x004\x00,\x00 \x001\x008\x003\x002\x00,\x00 \x001\x009\x000\x003\x00\r\x00\n']
```

I've tried rewriting the text file in case there was something corrupt about that particular file, and it still does the same thing. I'm not sure why because last time this worked fine.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Look at what does print(repr(g)) gives you

Comment: Is there a space before each line?

Comment: I did some fixing up of the formatting, but made some assumptions about the bullets.. there's no dashes in the actual file, right?

Comment: Hmm... It looks like each character is two bytes wide.

Comment: There are no spaces before or after each line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a comma-separated file with UTF-16 encoding (hence the `\x00` null bytes). You'll have to decode the input from UTF-16, like so:

```
import codecs

closure_date=[]
closure_starttime=[]
closure_endtime=[]
with codecs.open('Observed_closure_info.txt', 'r', 'utf-16-le') as g:
    g.next() # skip header line
    for line in g:
        date, start, end = line.strip().split(', ')
        closure_date.append(date)
        closure_starttime.append(start)
        closure_endtime.append(end)
```

Comment: Yes this worked, thank you! Sorry, I'm an amateur programmer so this is a little foreign to me. And then to skip the first line which is a header?

Comment: @Melinda:  That's why he has the line `g.next() # skip header line`.  It can also be written `next(g)`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
g = open('Observed_closure_info.txt', 'r')
closure_date=[]
closure_starttime=[]
closure_endtime=[]
file_data1 = g.readlines()
for line in file_data1[1:]:
    data1=line.decode('utf-16').split(',')
    closure_date.append(str(data1[0]))
    closure_starttime.append(str(data1[1]))
    closure_endtime.append(str(data1[2]))
```